# No maximize and restore animations

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, I have enabled window amimations. They work when minimizing, restore from minimize, open and close windows, but do not work when maximizing and restoring from maximize. Is there a way to enable them?

Comment: I don't believe there is an animation for going between windowed and maximized modes.

Comment: @techie007 there was in Win95-WinXP.

Comment: [Aero](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/what-is-the-aero-desktop-experience) is a different beast.  See: [Windows 7: No restore up/down animations in Aero?](http://www.sevenforums.com/backup-restore/46506-no-restore-up-down-animations-aero.html)

Comment: @techie007 it seems Aero is buggy or unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

The max to restore is so fast , but i think there is a few tween frames, and there is no "fading".

I just tested by Video Recording the Restore and Max, on windows7 and there was No animation at all , what I was seeing was just the blur of it switching and different elements of the programs redrawing etc.  (plus the usual cmos update rate rolling shutter of the camera)

The buttons to control all that stuff are here. 
[[image: Pic of Visual settings]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv34R.png)

I think You already know where the controls are and have it on.  I do not remember the Default Xp having anything much more special.
I put sounds on these movements in the sounds panel even if I turn the animation off, it gives more of a feel for what occured than the quick animations.  The sounds I had applied both in 7 and XP were much shorter sounds for Max restore , than for minimising.  With window items taking 2/3rd of the screen already, jumping to full always seemed like a shorter move.

I am sure there are differences, the whole grafics thing changed between the 2, but i got used to any change fast?